# Как получить ссылку на скачивание файла pyrogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, pyrogram

существует ли способ получить ссылку на скачивание файла, который был отправлен пользователем в Telegram чат? В своём проекте я использую pyrogram, но не обязательно чтобы использовалась именно эта библиотека